# How to create a mock Oracle ADW database in Python for integration testing?

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, integration-testing

I am currently migrating data from AWS Redshift to Oracle ADW. I use postgres to create a mock database and run integration tests to simulate how my queries would run in production environment. Postgres is a good candidate for mocking Redshift database as they are similar, but that is not the case for Oracle ADW. I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions on how I could create a mock database that has the same syntax constraints as Oracle ADW.

I already know how to create mock connections to write unit tests. However, these integration tests help us validate pipelines end to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the Oracle XE database. It is free to use, is "real" Oracle, and supports most basic and several advanced features, with some resource limitations. It can be deployed in a variety of ways; not sure what would work best for you, but you can check it out here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html